# How to optimise my solution?

Tags: algorithm

I recently encountered a problem which goes
like this :

A student is given N number of
questions and T time in total. Each question
requires different time to complete and carries
different marks. The problem asks to find the
maximum marks the student can get by
attempting some of the N questions within T
time (Assuming if a question is attempted, it
must be fully completed,no partial attempt of a
question is allowed).

I tried to solve the problem by computing all
possible combinations of questions which takes
<= T seconds to complete but soon found out
its ineffective for large datasets.

How can I optimise my solution? Is there any
alternative solution available?

Comment: Do you know what questions will be attempted by the student? Is there a given input for this? What programming language? What have you done so far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specifically about programming, and seems to be more a math problem.

Comment: @Donnacha I am required to find what questions should be attempted. (Input consists of a list of questions (I mean associated time and marks))

Comment: @Mark It is a programming problem. Specifically this problem belongs to the class of Dynamic Problems. And as mentioned in one of the answers it is similar to 0-1 Knapsack Problems

Comment: In that case, you are simply not providing sufficient information, as your question doesn't demonstrate any attempt to solve it yourself. SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a variant of the well known [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: You're right, even more specific than the 1-D bin-packing problem.  :)